# (Spark Schedular) What's the difference between Fair and FIFO inside a spark job pool?

Tags: apache-spark, bigdata, job-scheduling

I know that for spark we could set different pools as Fair or FIFO and the behavior can be different. However, inside the fairscheduler.xml we could also set individual pool to be Fair or FIFO and I tested several times as their behavior seems to be the same. Then I took a look at the spark source code and the schedulingAlgorithm is like this:

```scala
/**
 * An interface for sort algorithm
 * FIFO: FIFO algorithm between TaskSetManagers
 * FS: FS algorithm between Pools, and FIFO or FS within Pools
 */
private[spark] trait SchedulingAlgorithm {
  def comparator(s1: Schedulable, s2: Schedulable): Boolean
}

private[spark] class FIFOSchedulingAlgorithm extends SchedulingAlgorithm{
  override def comparator(s1: Schedulable, s2: Schedulable): Boolean = {
    val priority1 = s1.priority
    val priority2 = s2.priority
    var res = math.signum(priority1 - priority2)
    if (res == 0) {
      val stageId1 = s1.stageId
      val stageId2 = s2.stageId
      res = math.signum(stageId1 - stageId2)
    }
    res < 0
  }
}

private[spark] class FairSchedulingAlgorithm extends SchedulingAlgorithm{
  override def comparator(s1: Schedulable, s2: Schedulable): Boolean = {
    val minShare1 = s1.minShare
    val minShare2 = s2.minShare
    val runningTasks1 = s1.runningTasks
    val runningTasks2 = s2.runningTasks
    val s1Needy = runningTasks1 < minShare1
    val s2Needy = runningTasks2 < minShare2
    val minShareRatio1 = runningTasks1.toDouble / math.max(minShare1, 1.0)
    val minShareRatio2 = runningTasks2.toDouble / math.max(minShare2, 1.0)
    val taskToWeightRatio1 = runningTasks1.toDouble / s1.weight.toDouble
    val taskToWeightRatio2 = runningTasks2.toDouble / s2.weight.toDouble

    var compare = 0
    if (s1Needy && !s2Needy) {
      return true
    } else if (!s1Needy && s2Needy) {
      return false
    } else if (s1Needy && s2Needy) {
      compare = minShareRatio1.compareTo(minShareRatio2)
    } else {
      compare = taskToWeightRatio1.compareTo(taskToWeightRatio2)
    }
    if (compare < 0) {
      true
    } else if (compare > 0) {
      false
    } else {
      s1.name < s2.name
    }
  }
}
```

In the fairSchedulingAlgorithm, if s1 and s2 are from a same pool, the minshare, runningtask and weight should the same value and in this way we could always get the return value as false. So they are not Fair but FIFO. My fairscheduler.xml is like this:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>

    <allocations>
      <pool name="default">
        <schedulingMode>FAIR</schedulingMode>
        <weight>3</weight>
        <minShare>2</minShare>
      </pool>
      <pool name="cubepublishing">
          <schedulingMode>FAIR</schedulingMode>
          <weight>1</weight>
          <minShare>0</minShare>
      </pool>
    </allocations>
```

And spark.scheduler.mode is:

```
# job scheduler
spark.scheduler.mode              FAIR
spark.scheduler.allocation.file   conf/fairscheduler.xml
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Please [copy-paste](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/48653370/edit) in your code, instead of using screenshots. We have very good code formatting, which is available from the edit menu.

Answer (score 0):

When you submit your jobs in the cluster either with spark-submit or any other mean, it will be given to Spark schedulers which is responsible to materialize logical plan of your jobs. In spark, we have two modes.

**1. FIFO**
By default, Spark’s scheduler runs jobs in FIFO fashion. Each job is divided into stages (e.g. map and reduce phases), and the first job gets priority on all available resources while its stages have tasks to launch, then the second job gets priority, etc. If the jobs at the head of the queue don’t need to use the whole cluster, later jobs can start to run right away, but if the jobs at the head of the queue are large, then later jobs may be delayed significantly.

**2. FAIR**
The fair scheduler also supports grouping jobs into pools and setting different scheduling options (e.g. weight) for each pool. This can be useful to create a high-priority pool for more important jobs, for example, or to group the jobs of each user together and give users equal shares regardless of how many concurrent jobs they have instead of giving jobs equal shares. This approach is modeled after the Hadoop Fair Scheduler.

Without any intervention, newly submitted jobs go into a default pool, but jobs’ pools can be set by adding the spark.scheduler.pool "local property" to the SparkContext in the thread that’s submitting them.